# Recv() returns 0 from DNS query (C)

Tags: c, networking, dns

So I've created a DNS proxy in C. I'm using DIG as the client program; it sends a query packet to my server, my server forwards it to a DNS, and my server receives the answers, then sends them back to the client.

My server is bound to a UDP socket; I'm transmitting the DNS packet via TCP. However, my recv() call (from the TCP socket) is always returning 0. I'll get the original query back, but without answers.

Code:

```
fromlen=sizeof(client);
recvfrom(UDPSock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&fromlen); //receive from client
int msglen=strlen(buffer);
connect(TCPSock,(struct sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest)); //connect to DNS
int m=send(TCPSock,buffer,msglen,0); //send packet to dns
recv(TCPSock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0); //this returns 0

//send back
sendto(UDPSock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,fromlen); //send message back`
```

The buffer is 300 bytes.

Comment: What are the return values of `connect()` and `send()`? Are they what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're not speaking the correct protocol.  The DNS/TCP/IP protocol is not identical to the DNS/UDP/IP protocol.  Read the RFCs describing the protocols and follow them.

Your more fundamental problem is a design problem with your code as given.  It doesn't really make sense, not least in terms of network overhead, to have one-connection-per-query TCP/IP on the back end when there's only UDP/IP on the front end.  Moreover: A properly written [forwarding proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#ForwardingProxy) has to cope with large UDP/IP packets, truncated responses, truncated and otherwise malformed *queries*, TCP/IP connection timeouts and resets, loop detection, and DNS/UDP/IP retry.  But this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: See RFC 5625 on how not to write a DNS proxy.

Comment: I plan to work out the connection details later; I'm simply trying to get a correct response from the DNS server first. I see the differences now... how would I go about sending a 2-byte length field?

Comment: Thank you; I figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from not checking for errors from any of the system calls one big problem is the [`strlen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strlen.3.html) use. The [`recvfrom(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html) tells you how many bytes it placed in your buffer (or `-1` for error). Some of these bytes could have zero values so the `strlen(2)` is not at all applicable in this case. Fix that and see if it helps. Otherwise you'd have to explain why you forward over TCP and connect on every packet.

Comment: I changed the strlen to sizeof(); I'm still not receiving a response from the server. I checked all the system calls for errors--recvfrom and sendto return 300, connect() returns 0, and send returns the correct number of bytes. (also 300) I hexdumped the packet and there's no formatting issues there. It appears that it's all hinging on the recv() call.

Comment: Use the return value of `recvfrom()` instead of `sizeof`. Then when TCP `recv()` returns zero it means the other end disconnected. See @JdeBP answer - you are not sending proper request, so the server just closes the connection on you.

Answer (score 0):

recv() returns zero when the other end disconnects. So you are making the other end disconnect rather than send any data. Probably it doesn't understand what you are sending.

Comment: I'm actually receiving answers now; I prefixed my packet transmission by sending/recving a 2-byte length field... but I'm not getting back the authority/additional record sections... almost there!